# GIMP Separate RGB -> CMYK plugin - how to get output color profile

Tags: gimp, conversion, cmyk

I use newest Ubuntu and newest GIMP, i have the plugin Separate installed. I try to convert image to CMYK. In a dialog in a drop-down list I have 16 RBG profiles to choose input profile, but none for CMYK output. There are .icc files with RGB profiles, but none with CMYK. I assume I should have some files with those profiles. Where can I get them from. Should I put them in specific place or anywhere, provided I specify good path in this dialog. Please help.